# SQL ON DELTE CASCADE does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl, cascade

I am currently writing on a Database with the Oracle SQL Developer and I want to use the ON DELETE CASCADE for my foreign keys but it doesn't work apparently. Here are the concerned statements. You may note that there arent any more tables, just these two for testing.

```
CREATE TABLE pizza
(   size NUMBER(3),
    price NUMBER(5,2),
    CONSTRAINT pk_pizza PRIMARY KEY (size, price)
);
CREATE TABLE pizzacondiment 
(   condiment VARCHAR(30),
    pizzasize NUMBER(3),
    pizzaprice NUMBER(5,2),
    CONSTRAINT pk_condiments PRIMARY KEY (condiment, pizzasize, pizzaprice)
    CONSTRAINT fk_condiments_pizza FOREIGN KEY (pizzasize, pizzaprice)
    REFERENCES pizza (size, price)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
);
```

Now, when I want to drop the table pizza the output says:

```
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
02449. 00000 -  "unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys"


*Cause:    An attempt was made to drop a table with unique or
           primary keys referenced by foreign keys in another table.


*Action:   Before performing the above operations the table, drop the
           foreign key constraints in other tables. You can see what
           constraints are referencing a table by issuing the following
           command:
           SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "tabnam";
```

Comment: Thanks Timur.  `ON DELETE CASCADE` applies to row-level deletions on the referenced (`pizza`) table, not dropping the entire referenced table.  Did you want to drop dependent tables (`pizzacondiment`) along with the parent table, or did you just want to be able to drop the parent `pizza` table (leaving an orphan `pizzacondiment` behind)?

Comment: @alexgibbs I want to drop the parent pizza with leaving an orphan pizzacondiment behind :)

Comment: Thanks Timur.  Ok you can drop `pizza` and leave `pizzacondiment` with all its (orphaned) data behind.  The drop command will wipe out the constraint in the process.  I'll post up an example.  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ON DELETE CASCADE` applies to row-level `DML` operations but won't affect `DDL` like `DROP`.  I'll add an example of how `ON DELETE` applies then look at a change that can be made to the drop statement to break the link between `pizza` and `pizzacondiment` but leave an orphaned `pizzacondiment` behind in a queryable state.

After creating the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PIZZA
(
  "SIZE" NUMBER(3),
  PRICE  NUMBER(5, 2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_PIZZA PRIMARY KEY ("SIZE", PRICE)
);

CREATE TABLE PIZZACONDIMENT
(
  CONDIMENT  VARCHAR(30),
  PIZZASIZE  NUMBER(3),
  PIZZAPRICE NUMBER(5, 2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_CONDIMENTS PRIMARY KEY (CONDIMENT, PIZZASIZE, PIZZAPRICE),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CONDIMENTS_PIZZA FOREIGN KEY (PIZZASIZE, PIZZAPRICE)
  REFERENCES PIZZA ("SIZE", PRICE)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And adding some test data:

```
INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (11,1.25);
INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (219,111.11);
INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (50,7.50);


INSERT INTO PIZZACONDIMENT VALUES ('Spinach',50,7.50);
INSERT INTO PIZZACONDIMENT VALUES ('Peppers',50,7.50);
INSERT INTO PIZZACONDIMENT VALUES ('Onions',50,7.50);
INSERT INTO PIZZACONDIMENT VALUES ('Tomatoes',219,111.11);
INSERT INTO PIZZACONDIMENT VALUES ('Mushrooms',11,1.25);
INSERT INTO PIZZACONDIMENT VALUES ('Olives',11,1.25);
```

We can see `ON DELETE CASCADE` in action when we delete the size=11 pizza:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CONDIMENT_COUNT FROM PIZZACONDIMENT WHERE PIZZASIZE = 11;

CONDIMENT_COUNT  
2
```

Then make the `delete`:

```
DELETE FROM PIZZA WHERE "SIZE" = 11;
1 row deleted.
```

And check the child table again:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CONDIMENT_COUNT FROM PIZZACONDIMENT WHERE PIZZASIZE = 11;

CONDIMENT_COUNT  
0
```

As you mentioned you'd like to `DROP` the `PIZZA` table but leave an orphan `PIZZACONDIMENT` behind, you can do that with an adjustment to your `DROP` syntax, using `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`.  This will drop any foreign keys that would have prevented the `DROP`, leaving orphan child table(s) behind.

```
DROP TABLE PIZZA CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

Table PIZZA dropped.
```

`pizzacondiment` is orphaned but still usable:

```
SELECT * FROM PIZZACONDIMENT WHERE CONDIMENT = 'Spinach'; 

CONDIMENT  PIZZASIZE  PIZZAPRICE  
Spinach    50         7.5
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! This will help a lot :-)

Comment: Thanks @Timur If any clarification I can provide just let me know.  When you believe your question has been answered(whether by this post or another) please consider accepting an answer; it helps to see the state of a question going forward.  Thanks

Comment: Amazing answer.  I had this exact same issue and this solved it.  Thank you!